# Passing data from one node express app to another in same/different domain

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I need to pass some data from one node express app A to another B that may/may not run on the same domain. I want to do this using a 301 redirection. I learnt that you can do this by a connect-flash node module but it works only across the same app middleware. Any suggestions or reference would be helpful. Thanks.

```
// App A
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

app.use(require('body-parser').json());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(flash());

app.post('/forceRedirect', function (req, res, next) {
    var dataRecieved = {
        requestHeaderVersion:req.get('version'),
        requestBodyParam:req.body.firstname,
        path:req.originalUrl
    };

    console.log('Data logging on node app A: ' +     JSON.stringify(dataRecieved));

    req.flash('testdata', 'it worked');    
    return res.redirect(301, 'http://mydomain/test') // Pass to     app  B that is on different domain

})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Node 1 listening on port 3000!')
})
```

---

```
//App B - running on different domain

var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express()

app.use(require('body-parser').json());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(flash());

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Node app B is hit! and recieved data from node app A is :' + JSON.stringify(req.flash('testdata')));
  res.end();
})

app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('Node app 2 listening on port 4000!') 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be if you really want a 301,

//APP A

```
 return res.redirect(301, 'http://mydomain/test/data1/data2')
```

//APP B

```
app.get('test/:data1/:data2', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.data1);
    console.log(req.params.data1);
```

});

**EDIT**

A better way would be

```
res.redirect(307, 'http://mydomain/test');
```

This will redirect the orginal content of the POST to another POST presumably in APP B.

Comment: Hi Kalana, thanks for your reply, however I will not be able to send a key value object to app B.